# Hook with jquery script is not working in wp-admin

Tags: jquery, wp-admin, hooks

This is the hook and script Im using, the jquery script itself is working as you can see [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mahish/4Fvvp/4/):

```
function my_custom_admin_footer(){

        echo '      
            <script type="text/javascript">

                jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                    $(".checkIt").change(function (e) {
                        if ($("input:checkbox:checked").length > 1) {

                            alert("Only one attribute is allowed.");
                            $(e.target).prop('checked', false);
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
        '; 
}

add_action('admin_footer', 'my_custom_admin_footer');
```

in wp-admin, i get only blank page instead,

the problem is definitely in jquery because simple alert script does work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    alert("Hello"); 
});
```

I don't get it. Although, I'm not pro in jquery neither php so maybe Im missing something. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blank page is a PHP fatal error. You need to either escape the single quotes or change them to double quotes.

`$(e.target).prop('checked', false);` -> `$(e.target).prop("checked", false);`

You can enable debugging in WordPress to see the PHP errors by setting WP_DEBUG to true in you wp-config.php file. You can also look in your server/PHP error log. The location of the log depends on your server set up.

Answer (score 1):

Your browser's error console will probably give you a hint as to what's wrong.

Change

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
```

to

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
```

jQuery is in noConflict mode, so the `$` does not contain the jQuery object. You correctly use `jQuery` for the ready function, but you have to pass the `$` as an argument to that function if you want to use `$` within.

Reference: [`wp_enqueue_script`: jQuery noConflict Wrappers](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers)

Comment: well that's what's wrong with your script from a *WordPress* perspective. If your issue is the javascript within, that's certainly off-topic here. what steps have you taken to debug the issue? have you looked at your browser's error console?

Comment: This all i got from error console – http://gyazo.com/7f8c45c84a763d8f413bcfda5ffa6193. Nothing about my script.